# Sigma algebra generated by a topology that in it's turn is generated by a class of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and f a function $f:X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Then f is measurable if $f^{-1}(a,+\infty) \in \mathcal{A}$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$. I think that the sets of the form $(a,+\infty)$ generate a topology (is it called the borel topology?) on $\mathbb{R}$.

I also know that there's a theorem that says that if a sigma algebra is generated by a class $\mathcal{G}$ then it is enough for a function $f: (X,\mathcal{A}) \mapsto (Y, \sigma(\mathcal{G}))$ to be measurable that 
 $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}) \subset \mathcal{A}$.

My question is:

If a sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$ is generated by a topology that in turn is generated by a class of sets $\mathcal{G}$ (so that $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\tau(\mathcal{G}))$. Is it enough for a function $f: (X,\mathcal{A}) \mapsto (Y, \mathcal{B})$ to be measurable that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}) \subset \mathcal{A}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in general.  For instance, let $X=Y$ be any uncountable set and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the set of singleton subsets of $Y$.  Then the topology $\tau(\mathcal{G})$ is the discrete topology, and $\sigma(\tau(\mathcal{G}))=\mathcal{P}(Y)$.

On the other hand, we could talke $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\mathcal{G})$, which is the algebra of all sets that are either countable or cocountable.  The identity map $f:X\to Y$ then satisfies $f^{-1}(G)\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $G\in\mathcal{G}$, but $f$ is not measurable.

More generally, you can expect to get similar examples whenever generating the topology from $\mathcal{G}$ requires you to take uncountable unions.

Comment: Ok, thankyou! Is it just a coincidence that it's true in the case I mentioned above?

Comment: It's not a coincidence: if every open set is a countable union of sets from $\mathcal{G}$, then $\sigma(\tau(\mathcal{G}))=\sigma(\mathcal{G})$.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you possibly know where I can find a proof of that?

Comment: The proof is trivial: $\tau(\mathcal{G})\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{G})$ in that case.